# How to remove cache items from datalist?

Tags: c#, jquery

[image]

I have bind datalist with data for autocomplete textbox and as you can see in below image, there is one partition with extra items which is coming from cache. 
So How can we remove the cache from datalist.

Comment: We need to see some code, understand the platforms (are you using MVC?) etc to provide help.

Comment: Yes, I am using MVC c#.
I am binding datalist by using following code. Here arrList is my array of addresses.

<option data-value='"+arrList[i].Value+"' value='"+arrList[i].Text+"' ></option>

Answer (score 4):

After some research this help me, hope helps you too.
set autocomplete to **off**.

```
<input id="Mydropdownlist" list="listdp" name="listdp" autocomplete="off">
```